# Problem when running try-state

Tags: try-runtime

I have been trying to run the try-state hook to check whether the Polkadot network passes all the checks.

I started a local node and imported the state from the Polkadot network.
When trying to run the try-state command like this:

```
./target/release/polkadot try-runtime \
    --runtime ./target/release/wbuild/polkadot-runtime/polkadot_runtime.wasm \
    -lruntime=debug \
    execute-block live \
    --try-state Collective \
    --uri ws://localhost:9944
```

I received the following error message:

```
error: Found argument '--try-state' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

Looking at https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/try_runtime_cli/ this command should work.

Also when following a chain instead of executing a single block this command works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typo in the docs. `live` belongs before `--uri`, not after `execute-block`.

Try this:

```
./target/release/polkadot try-runtime \
    --runtime ./target/release/wbuild/polkadot-runtime/polkadot_runtime.wasm \
    -lruntime=debug \
    execute-block \
    --try-state Collective \
    live --uri ws://localhost:9944
```